# CNContactPickerViewController search bar not working

Tags: ios, cncontactpicker

I came to know that search bar in CNContactPickerViewController doesn't allow to select searched contacts. I also look other stack overflow questions regarding this issue. It seems like iOS bug. But I want to know, is there any way to hide or disable search bar from CNContactPickerViewController? Because if this doesn't work then I don't want to show it.

Comment: Aamir, what did you find out about this? I think it's crazy that this is still broken in Xcode 9 and iOS 11. It's been years!

Comment: its working for me

Comment: its not working. @iOS_Developer Could you post your working steps here

Comment: Hii @Aamir Anwar. Did you find the answer?

Comment: @vijju No, i didn't find the solution. Else, i fetched contacts and use custom UIViewController according to requirement.

Comment: @AamirAnwar ok ,Thank you for the response